C++ decimal separator syntax mistake
I recently made a syntax mistake by writing this:
b = (float)a*0,1;

instead of:
b = (float)a*0.1;

I am surprised to find out that the first line don't even put a compilation error. I am even more confuse to see that the following line produce compilation error:
float b = (float)a*0,1;

Can someone explain me why the third line is a syntax error but not the first (in fact it is) ?

Sometimes you'll get a compiler warning (usually something like blah has no effect), but when the compiler sees syntactically valid code, no matter how wrong-headed it may be logically, it compiles it.

Example of compiler configured to issue a warning: https://godbolt.org/z/jrrE7bnEW

offtopic: if a is an integer you do not need the cast. And when you do need the cast you should rather use a proper one static_cast<float>(a)

This ...

b = (float)a*0,1;


... is a statement.  Specifically, an expression statement.  In the expression within, the comma (,) is an operator, with operand expressions b = (float)a*0 and 1.  The overall statement is equivalent to
b = (float)a*0; 1;

, and the comma expression itself evaluates to the value of the second operand (1), which happens to be ignored in this case.
On the other hand, this ...

float b = (float)a*0,1;


... is a (malformed) declaration.  The comma here is not the comma operator, but rather a separator between items being declared.  This declaration is erroneous because the second item does not contain a declarator designating the item being declared.  (The declarator in the first item is b.)
